# If two functions f,g are both discontinuous at some point a in the domain, does this mean that the sum f+g is also discontinuous at a?

Tags: real-analysis

Real analysis question. Having trouble either coming up with a counterexample where the sum would be continuous at a, or proving that the sum would be discontinuous at a for all cases.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1/x, g(x)=-1/x$ and their sum at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Take any fonction $f$ that is discontinuous at a point $x$. Then so is $g = -f$. But $f+g = 0$ is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x =0.
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}0 & \text{if } x \neq 0, \\
1 & \text{if } x =0.
\end{cases}$$